# What does $0 hold when called via a symlink?

Tags: linux, symlink

The `$0` shell parameter holds the name of the calling program. If you make a symbolic link named `my_command` in your home directory to the command `/usr/local/bin/command1` and you execute it by typing `./my_command`, what will be the value of `$0`? Can anyone also explain why? Thanks!

Comment: That's how `busybox` or `lvm` works... many commands in a single binary, called via symlink, and `$0` tells the binary what it was called as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$0` doesn't hold the name of the calling program but the name of the called program. The called program is `./my_command` so `$0` will be `./my_command` too.

The fact it is a symbolic link doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

A command line (or rather, in UNIX, an array of command line arguments), including what would become `$0`, is passed to the [`exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) call by the calling program.

Symlink resolution, shebang processing etc. is only done after that, by the system, as part of processing the `exec` call.

So, whatever the calling program (the shell in your case) specified as the first item in `argv` (`/.my_command` in your case) becomes `$0`.